# How to send an Encrypted Zip Archive as Mail Attachment in PHP?

Tags: php, email-attachments, php-ziparchive

I found answers on encrypting zip files and also on how to send files in mail attachments. Both in separate questions. So I combined the both to make it easier for others. This is a self answered question.

You will be able to generate a random unique password for each receiver and send the password along with the attachment in the mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note : Most Servers will mark the attachment as unsafe as they wont be able to scan the zip archive for malicious files.**

Following is the Code to send an Encrypted Zip Archive as mail attachment in PHP.

```
<?php

$file_key="password"; //Password for the Zip Archive

$receiver_name = "Receiver Name";
$receiver_email = "Receiver Email";

$sender_name = "Sender Name";
$sender_mail = "Sender Mail";

//Main Content
$main_subject = "Mail Subject";
$main_body = "Mail Body";

echo "Creating Zip Archive <br>";
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "final-level.zip";   //Zip File Name
if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)===TRUE) {
    $zip->setPassword($file_key);
    $zip->addFile(
        "./dir/test.txt", //File Directory
        "test.txt" //New File Name inside Zip Archive
    );
    $zip->setEncryptionName('text.txt', //New File Name
    ZipArchive::EM_AES_256); //Encryption 
    $zip->close();
}else{
    echo "Cannot open Zip file <br>";
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}
echo "Created Zip File <br>";
//#############################DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE#############################
$file = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
//Sending mail to Server
$retval = mail($receiver_email, $main_subject, "--$uid\r\nContent-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n$main_body \r\n\r\n--$uid\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"\r\n\r\n$file\r\n\r\n--$uid--", "From: $sender_name <$sender_mail>\r\nReply-To: $sender_mail\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$uid\"\r\n\r\n");

//#############################DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE#############################
//Output
if ($retval == true) {
    echo "Message sent successfully...";
} else {
    echo "Error<br>";
    echo "Message could not be sent...Try again later";
}
//Delete File from Server
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    unlink($filename);
}
echo "Unlinked File from Server <br>";
echo "Done <br>";
```